# Is there a keyboard shortcut to shut down OSX?

Tags: shortcut, shutdown

Is there a keyboard shortcut to shut down OSX 10.10.1?

Comment: `Command` `Shift` `/` will trigger the help menu. Press `->` to get to the shutdown menu. Then you can scroll up to the shutdown option. Done.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Power ⌽</kbd>  will perform a standard shutdown, asking to if you wish to save open documents first.

There's a list of OS X shortcuts at Apple KB [Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/HT201236)